# Python 3.5 | split List and export to Excel or CSV

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I scrape a website with Python 3.5 (BeautifulSoup) and the result is a list. The values are stored in a variable called "project_titles".

The values look like:

```
project_titles = ['I'm Back. Raspberry Pi unique Case for your Analog Cameras', 'CitizenSpring - App to crowdsource & map safe drinking water', 'Shoka Bell: The Ultimate City Cycling Tool']
```

I want to split the values at the comma and export this to an Excel file or CSV.

I need the values in an Excel like:

- Cell A1: I'm Back. Raspberry Pi unique Case for your Analog Cameras
- Cell B1: CitizenSpring - App to crowdsource & map safe drinking water
- Cell C1: Shoka Bell: The Ultimate City Cycling Tool

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a list of strings conforming to the columns required in your CSV file you can simply write the list out using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#module-csv) module:

```
import csv

project_titles = ["I'm Back. Raspberry Pi unique Case for your Analog Cameras", 'CitizenSpring - App to crowdsource & map safe drinking water', 'Shoka Bell: The Ultimate City Cycling Tool']

with open('projects.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerow(project_titles)
```

After running this code the output CSV file would contain:

```
I'm Back. Raspberry Pi unique Case for your Analog Cameras,CitizenSpring - App to crowdsource & map safe drinking water,Shoka Bell: The Ultimate City Cycling Tool
```

which you can import into Excel.

Comment: hi... it works!!! Can you change the code, that the values will be insert to the columns. Like A1, A2, A3 and so on. Sorry for that

Comment: When you import the CSV file the values will automatically go into the cells named A1, B1, C1 etc. If you want to specifically add headers to the file, just write them as the first row using `writerow(['A1', 'B1', 'C1'])`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `project_titles` is already a list containing the strings you want, it's easy to use `pandas` (can be installed together with one of the scientific Python distributions, see [scipy.org](http://scipy.org)) with the following short code:

```
import pandas as pd

project_titles = ["I'm Back. Raspberry Pi unique Case for your Analog Cameras", 
               'CitizenSpring - App to crowdsource & map safe drinking water', 
               'Shoka Bell: The Ultimate City Cycling Tool']


d = pd.DataFrame(project_titles)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx') 
d.to_excel(writer, 'my_data', index=False, header=False) 
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a very simple code

```
project_titles = ["I'm Back. Raspberry Pi unique Case for your Analog Cameras", 'CitizenSpring - App to crowdsource & map safe drinking water', 'Shoka Bell: The Ultimate City Cycling Tool']

with open('data.csv',"w") as fo:
    fo.writelines(",".join(project_titles))
```